# CryptoJS Decryption Malformed UTF-8 Data Error in Angular Application ONLY in Production

Tags: angular, cryptojs

I am using `Angular 14` and `CryptoJS` for Decryption. Interestingly the decryption works in development/debug mode. But when I build the application and move it to production, the malformed utf-8 data error shows up.
I tried to remove the warnings by including `commonjs` in the `angular.json` file

```
 "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["crypto-js"]
```

However that only removed the warning. The malformed data error seems to persist.

The decryption service looks like this:

```
 decrypt(decryptMe: string): string {
    let _key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.secretKey);
    let _iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(this.secretKey);
    let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(decryptMe, _key, {
        keySize: 16,
        iv: _iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Iso10126
      }
    );

    return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  }
```

Can anyone help with this.

Comment: For an analysis the encryption code and/or complete sample data is missing. Note that the ECB mode does not use an IV and that the code is vulnerable (key as IV, ECB).

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I had unfortunately not added the key in the Production Environment. It was only available in dev mode. Unfortunately the error message was somewhat misleading.